# Access data from ZFS encrypted drive

Tags: linux-mint, zfs

I need to access data from the `/home` directory from an ZFS encrypted drive. The drive was previously set up with encryption on a Linux Mint system during the installation process.

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Which dataset contains my user data (for example `/home/astudent/Documents/`)?
2. Which parameters do I have to configure in order to mount only the dataset that contains my user data?

Regarding question 1:
`zfs list` gives me the following output:

```
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                             1.12G   646M       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                        1.12G   646M       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_54i4di                          1.12G   646M     1.12G  /boot
rpool                                              416G  41.6G      192K  /tmp
rpool/ROOT                                         415G  41.6G      192K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di                           415G  41.6G      410G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/srv                       192K  41.6G      192K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/usr                      2.64M  41.6G      192K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/usr/local                2.45M  41.6G     2.45M  /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var                      5.00G  41.6G      192K  /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/games                 192K  41.6G      192K  /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/lib                  4.25G  41.6G     4.03G  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/lib/AccountsService   244K  41.6G      244K  /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/lib/NetworkManager   1.42M  41.6G     1.42M  /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/lib/apt              94.3M  41.6G     94.3M  /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/lib/dpkg              127M  41.6G      127M  /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/log                   770M  41.6G      770M  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/mail                  192K  41.6G      192K  /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/snap                  192K  41.6G      192K  /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/spool                 276K  41.6G      276K  /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_54i4di/var/www                   192K  41.6G      192K  /var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                    5.57M  41.6G      192K  /
rpool/USERDATA/astudent_dv3ufv                     192K  41.6G      192K  /home/astudent
rpool/USERDATA/root_dv3ufv                        5.20M  41.6G     5.20M  /root
rpool/keystore                                     518M  42.1G     63.4M  -
```

Is my data in `rpool`, `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu54i4di` or `rpool/USERDATA/astudent_dv3ufv`? Do I need the `rpool/keystore`?

Regarding question 2:
I tried modifying some parameters for `rpool` and mounting the dataset. `zfs get name,keylocation,keyformat,mountpoint,canmount,keystatus,mounted,encryption rpool` gives me the following output:

```
NAME   PROPERTY     VALUE                                     SOURCE
rpool  name         rpool                                     -
rpool  keylocation  file:///home/astudent/Desktop/system.key  local
rpool  keyformat    raw                                       -
rpool  mountpoint   /tmp                                      local
rpool  canmount     off                                       local
rpool  keystatus    unavailable                               -
rpool  mounted      no                                        -
rpool  encryption   aes-256-gcm                               -
```

I found a `system.key` file in nautilus file manager and copied it to the Desktop. Then I set this as the `keylocation` parameter for the dataset. I also changed the mountpoint to `/tmp` because I was afraid that mounting to `/` would break my system.

I would like to be prompted for my passphrase and mount only the datapool of interest to lets say `/mnt`.

I am running Linux Mint 21.3.